# How to auto post php form imported data

Tags: php, post, foreach, submit

```
1.txt
 aaaaaaaaaa
 bbbbbbbbbb
 cccccccccc
 ......
```

Code:

```
`$post_data = array( 'user_data' => array(
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'max_connections' => $max_connections,
'is_restreamer' => $restreamer,
'member_id' => $reseller,
'created_by' => $reseller,
'is_trial' => $is_trial,
'exp_date' => $expire_date,
'bouquet' => json_encode( $bouquet_ids ) ) );

$opts = array( 'http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );
$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=create", false, $context ) );
// $obj = $api_result;
// $name = $obj->{'username'};
// $pass = $obj->{'password'};
print_r($api_result);
// print_r($post_data);    
?>

</div>
<div class="content">
<?php
$path = "1.txt";
$file = fopen($path, 'r');
$data = fread($file, filesize($path));
fclose($file);

$lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo '<form id="submit" action="#add1.php" method="post" >

<div class="form-group">
<div style="width:100%; background:#eeeeee;">
<button type="multiselect" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">ENTER</button>
<input type="hidden" name="macadress" id="macadress" value= '. $line.'>'.$line.'';

  echo '</form>';
}
?>
</div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()}; // sleep(1);
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

</script>
```

Hello all.

I use below code and many data listed when run php. (1000-1500 pcs) need to click one by one for submit lines.

imported data from txt (1.txt) file and listed line by line. all lines have submit button and send by click submit button. How to auto post created lines with 1 second delay.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is issue a POST request for each line of a file, it would probably be easier to do this with a command line script, rather than using a web page, and would avoid any timeout issues.  Using the curl functions would be straightforward to do this

Comment: I just made this code for display data and post one by one. but actually no need display data. just post automaticaly is okay. Can you give me sample code according to my php code?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

You could try a script something like this.  It includes a one second delay between each POST.  You would need to customise it a little depending on how your destination server responds to a successful call.

NB this is a command line script - I wouldn't attempt to run it via a web browser as it will likely time out if you have a large number of records.

```
<?php

// the URL you will be POST-ing to
$url = 'http://somewhere/add1.php';

// the source of your data
$path = '1.txt';

$fh = fopen($path, 'r');
if (!$fh) {
    echo 'Could not open file!' . PHP_EOL;
}

while ($line = trim(fgets($fh))) {

    echo 'Sending ' . $line . '...';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
            'submit' => 'ENTER',
            'macaddress' => $line,
        ],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ]);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // check that $result indicates success
    // this will depend on how your endpoint responds
    // example:
    // if ($result == 'OK') {
        echo 'OK' . PHP_EOL;
    // } else {
    //  echo 'FAILED' . PHP_EOL;
    // }
    
    curl_close($ch);

    // wait a second before sending the next one
    sleep(1);
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Hello Rob could you please help me about below issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are awesome. Its sending lines one by one. but can not received line from data page.

> ($username = $_POST['macadress'];)

```
    <?php
$panel_url = 'http://send_data_to_server/';
$username = $_POST['macadress'];
$password = 'Pop';
$max_connections = 1;
$restreamer = 0; //allow restream 0 no 1 yes
$reseller = 2; //set with reseller id
$is_trial = 0; //set 0 or 1

$bouquet_ids = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 );//add bouquet id
$expire_date = strtotime( "+15 month" );
###############################
$post_data = array( 'user_data' => array(
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'max_connections' => $max_connections,
'is_restreamer' => $restreamer,
'member_id' => $reseller,
'created_by' => $reseller,
'is_trial' => $is_trial,
'exp_date' => $expire_date,
'bouquet' => json_encode( $bouquet_ids ) ) );

$opts = array( 'http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );
$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=create", false, $context ) );   
?>
```

Comment: That's a different piece of code, I don't see how it's related.  Do you need `$api_result` when POST-ing your data to `add1.php`?

Comment: If somehow this code is necessary, it appears to need a 'macaddress' value supplied to it.  If you're running this from the command line, you could specifiy this as the first argument to the script, and switch `$_POST['macaddress']` to `$argv[1]`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. my fault. your code works perfectly. only the error below has been revised. You've been very helpful. Thanks... ^^
 $username = $_POST['macadress']; to $username = $_POST['macaddress'];